# Lost some intellisense in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Getting to grips with Visual Studio 2010,

This compiles:

```
var x = System.Web.Security.Membership.GetUser();
```

And runs, however VS2010 gives no intellisense for `x` and reports it just as a 'local variable'.

Has anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS2010 messed up, even though it was telling me the project was running at .net 4.0, changing it to 3.5 then back to 4.0 again fixed it.

Comment: In my case, I was working on a 3.5 project; other 3.5 projects in the same solution had intellisense working, and all projects compiled fine. Switching the non-intellisense project to 4.0, then back to 3.5 restored intellisense.

Answer (score 5):

this perhaps?

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/02/26/no-intellisense-with-vs-2010-rc-and-how-to-fix-it.aspx

if you have upgraded your preferences are copied, however if you have something like [resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) installed your intellisense preferences are actually turned off as resharper reimplements this.

Comment: Switched it off and on again, no luck.